# Android : Phone shaking pattern can be used for verification?

Tags: android, android-layout, authentication, android-fragments, android-activity

I need to add a shake feature in my android application. I am planning to do this :

First time user will shake phone and register one shake pattern, this shake pattern should be stored in local SQL Lite database. Next time when user open application at that time application will ask user to shake his/her phone again and previously stored shake pattern will be match. If its same then application will allow user to access something.

How much feasible is this idea? This idea will work robust fully?

As I now I am able to store shaking speed in database and next time I am trying to match with previously registered shake speed. This is working but it not looks secure way to verify user.

Guys, Please share your ideas for the same. It its possible then how can I implement in my application, please give me hint or tips.

Thanks in advanced.
Regards

Comment: it should not be tagged with `security`

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski thanks for pointing out. Let me remove this